# VB.NET Threading for large datasets

Tags: vb.net, multithreading

I have a VB.NET cash flow model that produces cash flows for a given loan portfolio.  Currently, the model runs on a single thread and works well for smaller datasets (usually a few thousand loans).  For a database of 250,000+ loans, I am changing the model to be multi-threaded so it can process cash flows of numerous loans simultaneously.  I ran 2,000 loans and total execution time (with writes to SQL DB) went from 7.5 minutes to under 90 seconds.  Each thread takes only a few seconds to run.  What advice do you have for running a large database of 250k to 300k loans on a single server with only 8MB RAM ?  Thread Pooling ?  How many max threads can I have running ?    Thanks in advance!

Comment: > vb.net > loan portfolio >mfw

Comment: The number of threads to use depend on the number of CPU core and the wait time for each process (ex: waiting for a db query). I would be more worried with the memory usage if you only have 8MB. This mean smaller objects/list.